# Why ffmpeg ignores output fps?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following ffmpeg command that streams an input to an RTMP endpoint:

```
ffmpeg 
    -re 
    -i - 
    -r 30 
    -vf scale=852:480 
    -c:v libx264 
    -pix_fmt yuv420p 
    -profile:v main 
    -preset veryfast 
    -x264opts "nal-hrd=cbr:no-scenecut" 
    -minrate 3000 
    -maxrate 3000 
    -g 60 
    -c:a aac 
    -b:a 160k 
    -ac 2 
    -ar 44100 
    -f flv 
    Some RTMPURL/ Some RTMPKey
```

This command works but the output frame rate is not respected. It drops to 6 fps. I need it to be always 30 fps.

Why is it not respected?

Comment: Share full log.